# Showing that two sets span the same subpace

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, orthonormal, gram-schmidt

Let's say that I have a linearly independent set of vectors $V=\{V_1,...,V_n\}$ on a vector space $W$. Performing Gram-Schmidt orthonormalization on V vectors I get the set of vectors $U=\{U_1,...U_n\}$. How can I show that these two sets, in fact, span the same subspace of $W$?

Comment: Each of the $U_i$ lies in the span of the $V_j$ and vice versa...

Comment: Prove it by induction since this is how Gram Schmidt is defined.